# Number Of Ways To Traverse a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Consider a binary tree of n nodes. For the sake of example consider the following tree:

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
           \
            8
```

How many different ways can I fully traverse the tree starting from the root (top) node and only moving to un-visited nodes that are directly connected to ones that have already been visited (i.e. I can go from 1 to 2 to 4 but then to 3)?

Comment: Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: @sharky Could you elaborate? I have seen this page put I couldn't find an answer to my question there.

Comment: you mean number of explorations, not traversals since a traversal  means following a path ?  e.g. if you have visited {1, 2} you can visit 4,5 or 3?

Comment: @svs Yes, I mean that if you have visited {1, 2} you can visit 4,5, or 3

Comment: The answer depends on more than n. For example, a binary tree with only left nodes has only one enumeration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have more luck asking on the Math Stack exchange.

You are asking for the number of linear extensions of the binary tree considered as a poset.  Although I can see no general formula, one can solve this recursively as follows:

Find the number of ways of traversing the left and right subtrees (the empty tree is trivially traversed in 1 way).  Call these T_L and T_R.  Let #L and #R be the cardinality (size) of the left tree and right tree respectively.  Then the number of ways of traversing the whole tree is

T_L * T_R * (#L + #R choose #L)

because we can traverse the left tree in T_L ways, the right tree in T_R ways (independent of how we traverse the right tree), and we can interleave the left and right trees in (#L + #R choose #L) ways.

In your example there are two ways of traversing the left tree, and three ways of traversing the right tree and (7 choose 3) is 35, so there are 2*3*35 = 210 ways of traversing the tree.

Comment: what is the choose in #R choose #L?

Comment: This is the binomial coeficient, (n choose k) is the number of ways of choosing k things from a set of n distinguished things.  The formula is n!/(k! * (n-k)!) where ! means factorial

Answer (score 1):

Programmatic verification of @deinst's answer, with Prolog:

```
traverse([], []) :- !.
traverse(F, [N|P]) :-
    % select a frontier node from F
    select(t(N,C), F, Rem),
    % append all new accessible children to the frontier
    append(C, Rem, NewF),
    % traverse the remaining set
    traverse(NewF, P).

tree(X) :-
    X = t(1,[t(2,[t(4,[]), t(5,[])]),t(3,[t(6,[]), t(7,[t(8,[])])])]).

do :-
    tree(X),
    findall(P, (traverse([X], P), write_ln(P)), Ps),
    length(Ps, L),
    write_ln(L).
```

This does indeed return 210 possibilities, as suggested for your example tree.

```
?- do.
[1,2,4,5,3,6,7,8]
[1,2,4,5,3,7,8,6]
[1,2,4,5,3,7,6,8]
[1,2,4,3,6,7,8,5]
[1,2,4,3,6,7,5,8]
[1,2,4,3,6,5,7,8]
[1,2,4,3,7,8,6,5]
[1,2,4,3,7,8,5,6]
[1,2,4,3,7,6,8,5]
...
[1,3,2,7,6,4,8,5]
[1,3,2,7,6,4,5,8]
[1,3,2,7,6,5,8,4]
[1,3,2,7,6,5,4,8]
210
true.
```